# Nested Collection in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

We are using backbone.js for creating MV* structures in javascript.

There is one particular requirement of nested collections. I would like to
know if anyone has idea on how we can achieve it.

We have created a view from a collections but now the problem is that how to create a collection of that view again?

We were trying to achieve the same by creating a parent reference in every
child collection object, but it fails to connect the parent collection views.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use [Backbone-Nested plugin](http://afeld.github.com/backbone-nested/). See also the [official wiki](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Extensions,-Plugins,-Resources) for the list of plugins and extension that solve a lot of common problems.

Comment: Backbone nested plugin gives info regarding model. I have updated my question, pls have a look